# Tensorflow Object Detection running very slowly

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using the Inception v2 rcnn model.

I have this code for my real time object detection program

```
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    with tf.gfile.GFile(MODEL_PATH, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

    sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)

image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
```

I noticed when I perform the object detection using this code

```
(boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
    [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
    feed_dict={image_tensor: image_expanded})
```

It's slow as hell..

The way my object detector works is by taking a screenshot of my screen and displaying it using OpenCV in a `while` loop

I'm only getting about 9 FPS.. e_e

I'm currently using an Nvidia Geforce MX150. Could the reason be that my GPU is slow?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, **Hardware GPU** can greatly affect the performance of the device. 

Although your hardware can impact the performance, there are still things you can change in the Software code.

Some tips on **improving the speed** of the inference/model.

1. Upgrade your Code into **TensorFlow version 2.x** to make use of the optimizations in the library. Read more about it in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2).
2. Convert your model to **TensorFlow Lite model** and use this for inference to improve **inference time** and **smaller memory footprint**, but with a little **trade-off for accuracy**.

To **convert** your model to TensorFlow Lite kindly refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert).

Hope this helps you. Cheers!